# spring security and GAE version

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-security

i am trying to use the code from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/gae-xml which goal is to use spring security in GAE. I am very surprised to see that in the pom.xml the version of appengine-api-1.0-sdk is 1.4.2 which is quite out of date : February 11, 2011. May be only the author has any idea of why this old dependency ?

Comment: have you tried contacting him? This does't seem like a question the community might answer.

Comment: I don't know how to contact him actually

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the sample has been around for a long time and we just haven't prioritized updating it. I created [SEC-2963](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2963) to address the issue. If you are able to update it, we'd love to see a PR that updates it!

Comment: Ok i thought there was another reason for that. I am asking this question because when i tried to update the version (1.9.19) of appengine-api-1.0-sdk and that i launched the sample locally i got a loop redirect  login?continue=/_ah/login  I can't test with the version 1.4.2 of the sdk because i am using appengine-maven-plugin which does not exist for that version